# Combining STOCH RSI and Macd for strategy

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create a strategy for pine that will use stoch rsi "k" instead of "close" for the macd.

If you open STOCH RSI indicator on a chart and click the 3 dots you can select "add indicator on..." if you do that and add MACD it creates the indicator I want. I can't figure out the script for it though and I would like it to be a strategy where buy/sell signals are indicated on chart candles.

If anything, I mainly need to know how to get macd to use stoch rsi like in the indicator. Can you point me in the right direction? or if you know how, script this for me.

Thank you
Taylor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to combine indicators take a look at the "new" option in the editor and select the indicators you are trying to combine in order to see their respective codes. In your case, you end up with the following script:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Stochastic RSI MACD")
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
//Stoch RSI Settings
smoothK = input(3, minval=1)
lengthRSI = input(14, minval=1),lengthStoch = input(14, minval=1)
//MACD Settings
fastlen = input(12),slowlen = input(26),siglen = input(9)
//----
rsi1 = rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
[fast,slow,hist] = macd(k,fastlen,slowlen,siglen)
//----
// Plot colors
col_grow_above = #26A69A
col_grow_below = #FFCDD2
col_fall_above = #B2DFDB
col_fall_below = #EF5350
col_macd = #0094ff
col_signal = #ff6a00
//----
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : 
  (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below) ), transp=0 )
plot(fast, title="MACD", color=col_macd, transp=0)
plot(slow, title="Signal", color=col_signal, transp=0)
```

Comment: yes thank you!! now I just need to turn it into a strategy.